# Selemium, Python - Поиск нужного элемента

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**Есть скрипт на определенные действия:**
1) Открытие страницы;
2) Выбор нужного значения из выпадающего списка ( исходя из суммы чисел в необходимых элементах );
3) Нажатие кнопки подтверждения.
После данных действий открывается алерт или попап с контрольной суммой.
**Вопрос:** 
Как можно найти элемент с данной контрольной суммой? Просто через элементы, к сожалению, у меня не выходит.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

try:
    link = 'http://suninjuly.github.io/selects1.html'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(link)
    z=int(browser.find_element_by_id("num1").text) + int(browser.find_element_by_id("num2").text)
    select = Select(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("select"))
    select.select_by_value(str(z))
    button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn").click()

finally:
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(browser.switch_to.alert.text)
```